# If naming a form element is deprecated, how do you get the value in POST from PHP?

Tags: php, html

I only know how to get POST values via named elements, such as:

```
<?php
$value = $_POST['value'];
```

But that would require naming my form elements, which does not validate.

The invalid code would look something like this:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="#">
<input type="text" name="text" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not validate"? That looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: what is the error returned by the validation?

Comment: I guess I was misinformed, that in strict DTD form elements can not have names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines you provide are valid. There must be some other part of the html that is invalid.

Comment: Ah, I've figured it out. Naming a form itself is invalid in strict DTD, but you can name the form elements.

Comment: Easy mistake to make. When in doubt best to run your code through the w3c validation service.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, the `name` attribute is not deprecated for form fields. However, standards say that there should be at least one block-level element wrapping fields within a form (such as a `fieldset` tag).